# Modifying a column with a button within the column

Tags: notebooks, text, cells

I want a column with textcells and a button to add an extra textcell:

```
Column[{Button["New line"],
TextCell["a", "Text", FontFamily -> "Times", FontWeight -> Plain, Editable -> True]},
Editable -> False]
```

How to do this? I want the first click to make it be like:

```
Column[{Button["New line"],
TextCell["However this has been edited", "Text", FontFamily -> "Times", FontWeight -> Plain, Editable -> True],
TextCell["a", "Text", FontFamily -> "Times", FontWeight -> Plain, Editable -> True]},
Editable -> False]
```

Comment: Could you please respond to Michael's answer. Does it fit your needs?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?  Using `InputField` is more convenient than figuring out how to write a text cell that stores its edited text in a dynamically updated variable.  (That's basically the function of `InputField` anyway.)

```
newline[Dynamic[texts_], text0_: ""] := (
   AppendTo[texts, text0];
   With[{n = Length[texts]},
    InputField[Dynamic[texts[[n]]], String, Appearance -> "Frameless",
      BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontWeight -> Plain, 
       Editable -> True}, FieldHint -> "enter text"]
    ]);

DynamicModule[{lines, texts = {}, btn},
 lines = {
   newline[Dynamic[texts], "However this has been edited"],
   newline[Dynamic[texts], "a"]};
 btn = Button["New line", AppendTo[lines, newline[Dynamic[texts]]]];
 Dynamic @ Column[{btn} ~Join~ lines, Editable -> False]
 ]
```